# iOS 7 - Get Unique ID in C

Tags: c, ios7, unique, udid

Can you help me on the below issue

on iOS 6.x, I used **gethostuuid** system call to get unique ID of iDevice, I just wonder if my app submit for iOS 7.x, it will be rejected by calling this api (gethostuuid)?

Is there any way to get Unique ID on iOS 7 (using C language) instead of calling gethostuuid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your **app specific Unique key**

why not try this

```
  UIDevice *myDevice=[UIDevice currentDevice];
  NSString *UUID = [[myDevice identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Answer (score 0):

KeyChainItemWrapper.h  may help 
you can see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html